# Como faço para gerar números aleatórios e sem repeti-los em um intervalo de tempo?

Tags: c, c++

Estou criando um 'jogo' no qual é necessário que o usuário escolha um intervalo, e neste intervalo, ele escolha quantos números aleatórios ele deseja gerar. Entretanto, nos números aleatórios gerados, não podem haver repetições, por exemplo:
Intervalo 1 a 10, mostrar 10 números aleatórios neste intervalo.
Não podem haver dois números 8 etc, porém não sei como pôr para não repeti-los. Segue o código:

```
printf("GERADOR DE N NÚMEROS ALEATÓRIOS\n");
printf("Digite o número máximo do intervalo: ");
scanf("%d", &intervalo); //Lê o intervalo máximo proposto pelo usuário.

printf("Intervalo proposto: [1 a %d]\n\n", intervalo); //Mostra na tela o intervalo proposto pelo usuário.

printf("Digite quantos números aleatórios e diferentes deseja gerar: ");
srand(time(NULL)); //Complementa o comando rand. Toda vez que executar o programa, os números gerados não estejam na mesma sequência que anteriormente.
scanf("%d", &n); //Lê a quantidade de números que serão mostrados na tela

for(i=1; i<=n; i++) // Coemça o intervalo em i, e mostra a quantidade de números até chegar em "n" que representa o intervalo proposto pelo usuário.
    printf("%dº número: %d\n",i, 1+(rand()%intervalo)); //Aqui é onde é imprimido na tela o número aleatório gerado, entretanto, ele precisa ser diferente do número anterior gerado.

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Não sei se entendi bem, mas você poderia armazenar estes números em um array e depois verificar se o número já existe no array. Caso exista, gere outro...

Comment: Felipe, o seu problema está resolvido? Você não chegou a aceitar a resposta ou dar algum feedback.

Answer (score 4):

Uma maneira de fazer isso é usar um `array`, `std:set` ou `std::unordered_set` (C++11 ou superior) para armazenar os valores intermediários. Os *sets* são especialmente interessantes umas vez que eles não permitem repetições:

```
std::unordered_set<int> numbers;
for(int i=1; i<=n; i++) { 
    int number = 1 + (rand() % intervalo);
    bool inseriu = numbers.insert(number).second;
    if (inseriu) {
        printf("%dº número: %d\n",i, number); 
    } else {
        printf("\t*%d é um número repetido, tentando novamente\n", number);
        i--;
    }
}
```

Veja que `unordered_set::insert` retorna um `pair<iterator,bool>`. O `iterator` aponta para o elemento recém inserido (ou o elemento com o mesmo valor), enquanto o `bool` indicada se o elemento foi inserido ou não.

A diferença entre o  `set` e o `unordered_set` é que o primeiro usa uma árvore ordenada (e.g., [Árvore rubro-negra](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81rvore_rubro-negra)) com tempo de inserção / busca `O(log(n))`. Já o segundo usa uma [tabela de dispersão](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabela_de_dispers%C3%A3o), sacrificando a ordem por tempos de inserção amortizados `O(1)`. No seu caso `unordered_set` parece fazer mais sentido.

---

Se o intervalo for suficientemente pequeno, uma solução alternativa é construir um `vector` contendo todo o intervalo, embaralhar e escolher os `n` primeiros elementos.

```
std::vector<int> numbers2(intervalo);
std::iota(numbers2.begin(), numbers2.end(), 1);
std::random_shuffle(numbers2.begin(), numbers2.end());
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    printf("%dº número: %d\n",i+1, numbers2[i]);    
}
```

Nesse exemplo a função [`iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) inicializa o `vector` com os números do intervalo e a função [`random_shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) embaralha esses valores. Esse algoritmo é interessante, por exemplo, para simular uma jogador embaralhando cartas.

**[Exemplo funcional no Ideone](http://ideone.com/VjGs8s)**

Answer (score 2):

Em C, a maneira usual de resolver o problema de aleatoriedade sem repetição é meter todos os valores possíveis num array, baralhar o array e escolher os primeiros `N` elementos.

```
int limite_inferior, limite_superior, quantidade;
// obter valores, eg
limite_inferior = 1;
limite_superior = 100;
quantidade = 30;

if (limite_superior < limite_inferior) /* erro */;
int alcance = limite_superior - limite_inferior + 1;
if (quantidade > alcance) /* erro */;

int *array = malloc(alcance * sizeof *array);
for (int k = 0; k < alcance; k++) array[k] = k + limite_inferior;

shuffle(array, alcance);
for (int k = 0; k < alcance; k++) printf("%d ", array[k]);
```

Para a função `shuffle()` ver, por exemplo, o artigo na Wikipedia sobre [Knuth Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).