# Adivinhar um número, e nas tentativas, através da porcentagem mostrar dicas

Tags: c, c++, random

Estou tentando criar um jogo em que o usuário deve determinar um intervalo e adivinhar um número aleatório que é gerado dentro deste intervalo. Quando o usuário insere um número para tentar adivinhar, o programa deve responder com uma das seguintes mensagens: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### O código até o momento está assim:

Sendo "resp" o número aleatório gerado, "tent" as tentativas, "num" o número que o usuário insere, e "n" o intervalo que o usuário determina em random().

```
int random();
void dicas(int num, int resp, int tent);

int main()
{
    int continuar=1,
        resp,
        tent,
        num,
        n;

    do{
        system("cls || clear");
        resp = random();

        printf("Comecou! Tente adivinhar o numero!\n\n");
        tent = 0;

        do{
            tent++;
            printf("Tentativa %d: ", tent);
            scanf("%d", &num);
            dicas(num,resp,tent);
        }while( num != resp);

        printf("Digite 0 para sair, ou qualquer outro numero para continuar: ");
        scanf("%d", &continuar);
    }while(continuar);

}

int random()
{
    int n;
    printf("Insira o valor maximo que pode ser sorteado: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Sorteando numero entre 1 e %d...\n",n);
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    return (1+rand()% n);
}

void dicas(int num, int resp, int tent)
{

    if(num>resp)
        printf("O numero sorteado e menor que %d\n\n", num);

    else if (num<resp)
        printf("O numero sorteado e maior que %d\n\n", num);

    else
        printf("Parabens! Voce acertou o numero em %d tentativas!\n\n", tent);
}
```

Meu problema está nas dicas, as atuais não correspondem ao que eu preciso fazer, porém não sei quais operações inserir para que ele mostre as respostas conforme a tabela.

Comment: Vale observar que na tag [tag:codeblocks] tem isso no final da descrição: "Se a dúvida não for sobre o Codeblocks, não use esta tag, mesmo que esteja usando o Codeblocks no seu projeto."

Comment: Isso está me cheirando a trabalho de Faculdade. (=

Comment: Sim. A primeira metade do trabalho está [nessa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100951/100) :) :) :). Felipe, no que exatamente você está com dúvida? No cálculo do percentual?

Comment: Sim, é na aplicação. Já tentei 3 operações diferentes e não deram certo. E sim, o trabalho é de faculdade, é um projeto de conclusão de matéria. A minha dúvida está dentro do "void dicas(int num, int resp, int tent)", preciso inserir as respostas da tabela ali, com as operações, etc.

Comment: Não ponhas o `srand()` dentro duma função que será chamada várias vezes: mete-o dentro da função `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

O que precisas é comparar a **diferença entre o alvo e o número escolhido** e o **alcance dos números possíveis**.

Isto é, imaginando que o número a acertar fosse `1` e que o utilizador *atirou* `4`: para um alcance entre `1` e `10` a percentagem é, aproximadamente (conta feita por alto, de cabeça), `40%`, para um alcance entre `1` e `1000000000` a percentagem é, aproximadamente, `0.000000001%`.

Ou seja ... a tua função `dicas()` precisa de receber o alcance (e não precisa de receber o número da tentativa)!

```
double dicas(int tiro, int alvo, int alcance) {
    return (100.0 * abs(tiro - alvo)) / alcance;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
void dicas(int num, int resp, int tent)
{

 float porcento = ((((double) num/resp)-1)*100);
 
 if(porcento < 0){
  porcento *= -1;
 }
 
 if (porcento == 0){
  printf("Parabens! Voce acertou o numero em %d tentativas!\n\n", tent);
 }else if (porcento > 0 && porcento < 10){
  printf("Muito quente\n\n");
 }else if (porcento > 10 && porcento < 20){
  printf("Quente\n\n");
 }else if (porcento > 20 && porcento < 30){
  printf("Frio\n\n");
 }else if (porcento > 30 && porcento < 40){
  printf("Muito frio\n\n");
 }else if (porcento > 40){
  printf("Continue tentando\n\n");
 }else{
  printf("Erro!\n\n");
 }

}
```